# How to run Standalone Android Studio Profiler?

Tags: android-studio, profiler

I want to open standalone profiler UI like on `Android Studio > View > Tool Windows > Profiler` but everytime i start [Standalone Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile#standalone-profilers) i got an error `invalid arguments`

```
2023-08-15 18:38:10.507 studio[7642:106665] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2023-08-15 18:38:10.509 studio[7642:106670] Current Directory: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin
2023-08-15 18:38:10.509 studio[7642:106670] parseVMOptions: STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS = (null)
2023-08-15 18:38:10.509 studio[7642:106670] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2023-08-15 18:38:10.509 studio[7642:106670] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2023-08-15 18:38:10.509 studio[7642:106670] parseVMOptions: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2023-08-15 18:38:10.510 studio[7642:106670] parseVMOptions: /Applications/Android Studio.app.vmoptions
2023-08-15 18:38:10.512 studio[7642:106670] parseVMOptions: /Users/administrator_1/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2022.3/studio.vmoptions
2023-08-15 18:38:10.512 studio[7642:106670] parseVMOptions: platform=20 user=1 file=/Users/administrator_1/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2022.3/studio.vmoptions
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
invalid args:[inspect]
Expected parameters: <project_file_path> <inspection_profile> <output_path> [<options>]
<inspection_profile> -- a profile name configured in the project or locally or a path to a inspection profile; can be skipped when one of -e|-profileName|-profilePath is used
Available options are:
 -d <directory_path>  --  directory to inspect, default is the whole project
-e                   --  use the inspection profile that is set for the project
-v[0|1|2]            --  verbose level. 0 - silent, 1 - verbose, 2 - most verbose
-profileName         --  name of a profile defined in the project
-profilePath         --  absolute path to a profile file
-format              --  report output format. One of xml|json|plain, default is xml
-changes             --  inspect uncommitted changes and report new problems
```

I don't know why i need to specify `project_file_path`, `inspection_profile` and `output_path` when i can select debuggable apps to see Memory, CPU usage real-time on `View > Tool Windows > Profiler`

anyone has suggestion how to run standalone Profiler UI like `View > Tool Windows > Profiler`?